# Autoprefixer Sublime text 3 error

Tags: sublimetext3

I trying to use autoprefixer but seen not working I have install node.js and I have confirm is on the $PATH. When I click autoprefixcss on command pallete give this pop up error

*"Autoprefixer 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 8: invalid continuation byte"*

on console the same

*error: Autoprefixer
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 8: invalid continuation byte*

I try install manually, same error
anyone now what's happening and what to do?

Comment: This is potentially an encoding problem. Can you include the relevant parts of the input that's causing it? That's generally a good idea if you're asking about errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Gulp for this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v259QplNDKk&list=PLLnpHn493BHE2RsdyUNpbiVn-cfuV7Fos&index=10